# FlashBuilder adds INTERNET permission even though it is not in my APP XML when building APK

Tags: android, flash, air

I have an Mobile AIR project in FlashBuilder 4.6(Using AIR 3.4) and I am having a real problem publishing an APK. Here is the section from my APP XML:

```
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>
]]></manifestAdditions>
```

For some reason, when I create an APK, the INTERNET permission is being tacked on the end of the manifest permissions block. Note that the application.xml in the asset/META-INF/AIR folder still looks correct.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this will work without any repercussions, but you could always unzip the APK, remove the INTERNET permission from the XML file, re-zip, run jarsigner, and then zipalign the new APK.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot more searching, I found my own answer:

> Note: When you bundle the runtime, ADT adds the INTERNET and
>   BROADCAST_STICKY permissions to your application. These permissions
>   are required by the AIR runtime.

BROADCAST_STICKY seems to no longer be required, but apparently when using captive runtime we cannot get around this.

Comment: This. Adobe has never given a reason why those are needed. Luckily they removed the BROADCAST_STICKY permission after some review, but the INTERNET one remains for no discernible reason.