# Adobe Air - Captive runtime adds internet permission request

Tags: android, air, android-manifest

I'm publishing an app with Flash CS6 and Air 3.4 for Android. If I publish with **captive runtime** I get a permission request for **internet** (android.permission.INTERNET) added. (Not set by me. If I publish the app without captive runtime it's not there)

Is this normal? If so - why does Adobe Air adds/needs that?

Thank you. Uli

Answer (score 0):

"When you bundle the runtime, ADT adds the INTERNET and BROADCAST_STICKY permissions to your application. These permissions are required by the AIR runtime"

[FlashBuilder adds INTERNET permission even though it is not in my APP XML when building APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039462/flashbuilder-adds-internet-permission-even-though-it-is-not-in-my-app-xml-when-b)