# flex mobile android permissions - full network access

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, permissions

is there any way to remove the permission for "full network access" on android systems? Removing this permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET
```

doesn't make any changes. My app don't need any connection to the network, so it doesn't care.

Comment: This is all you need. Just make sure that <uses-permission> for android.permission.INTERNET permission from the Android manifest file.

Comment: If you are using flex, then there are some entries defined in one of your xml files (dont remember the file names), which will get added to the generated APK by the flex builder automatically. Just remove those entries from that file and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I'm familar with the permission section in my *app.xml file. I've removed all permissions, but the dialog still appears. Is it a default permission from the flex mobile app or comes it maybe from the debug settings on the mobile device?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039462/flashbuilder-adds-internet-permission-even-though-it-is-not-in-my-app-xml-when-b